# Eggobjects flags generating error

Tags: maya, panda3d

I am totally new on panda3d so I need some support. I am trying to generate solid contente to import on panda3d but I tried so many time the script "eggObjectFlags()"".

The problems thats is generated all the times is that: "Cannot find eggObjectsFlags".

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in their document they are mentioned about a mel script to be sourced before using that command .. [Check Here](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Converting_from_Maya#Flagging_Objects_From_Maya)

Comment: I have done all these steps:
1 - Opened the sript editor;
2 - Run the scrip global proc int eggImportOptions;
3 - Type eggObjectsflags(), mark this text and drop on shelf 

After this and still do not recognize the command.

Comment: Another point is that the global script is eggImportOptions and the name is  eggObjectFlags. I am misuderstanding something